# AVCaptureSession addInput issues with ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, avcapturesession, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I have an application with AVCaptureSession which work correctly with previous iOS versions, but then I tried run it on device with ios8, application crashed sporadic.  but the problem wasn't solved. Exception getting in "[session addInput:input];" . Please advice how to resolve. Please verify my below code and im getting error in [session addInput:input];

> Printing description of error: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain
>   Code=-11852 "Cannot use Back Camera" UserInfo=0x17c076e0
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot use Back Camera,
>   AVErrorDeviceKey=,
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=This app is not authorized to use Back
>   Camera.}

```
#import "CameraViewController.h"
#import "MAImagePickerControllerAdjustViewController.h"
#import "PopupViewController.h"
#import "MAImagePickerFinalViewController.h"

@implementation CameraViewController

@synthesize vImagePreview;
@synthesize vImage;
@synthesize stillImageOutput;
@synthesize lFrameCount;
@synthesize session;
@synthesize device;
@synthesize oneOff;
@synthesize captureManager = _captureManager;
@synthesize flashButton = _flashButton;
@synthesize vImage1;
@synthesize vImage2;
@synthesize vImage3;
@synthesize vImage4;
@synthesize vImage5;
@synthesize vImage6;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark - UI Actions
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
-(IBAction) captureNow
{
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections)
    {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
        {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
            {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) { break; }
    }

    NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", stillImageOutput);
    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
    {
         CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment( imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
         if (exifAttachments)
         {
            // Do something with the attachments.
            NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
         }
        else
            NSLog(@"no attachments");

        NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

        NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *val1 = nil;

        if (standardUserDefaults)
        {
            val1 = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"clickTypeTwo"];
        }
        if([val1 isEqualToString:@"cameraType"])
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                [session stopRunning];

            });


             FinalViewController *finalView;
            if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
                finalView = [[FinalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:IS_IPAD()?@"FinalViewController_iPad":@"FinalViewController" bundle:nil];
            else
                finalView =[[FinalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:IS_IPAD()?@"FinalViewController_iPad":@"FinalViewController" bundle:nil];



            finalView.sourceImage = image;
            //finalView.imageFrameEdited = YES;
            CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
            transition.duration = 0.4;
            transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
            transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
            [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:finalView animated:NO];


        }
        else
        {

         [session stopRunning];
        AdjustViewController *adjustViewController;
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
            adjustViewController = [[AdjustViewController alloc] initWithNibName:IS_IPAD()?@"AdjustViewController_iPad":@"AdjustViewController" bundle:nil];
        else
            adjustViewController =[[AdjustViewController alloc] initWithNibName:IS_IPAD()?@"AdjustViewController_iPad":@"AdjustViewController" bundle:nil];




        adjustViewController.sourceImage = image;

        CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
        transition.duration = 0.4;
        transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
        [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:adjustViewController animated:NO];

        }

     }];
}


-(void)cropImageViewControllerDidFinished:(UIImage *)image{
  FinalViewController *finalView;
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
        finalView = [[MAImagePickerFinalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:IS_IPAD()?@"FinalViewController_iPad":@"FinalViewController" bundle:nil];
    else
        finalView =[[MAImagePickerFinalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:IS_IPAD()?@"FinalViewController_iPad":@"FinalViewController" bundle:nil];



    finalView.sourceImage = image;
    //finalView.imageFrameEdited = YES;
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.4;
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:finalView animated:NO];
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark - Video Frame Delegate
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput 
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer 
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection 
{ 
    //NSLog(@"got frame");

    iFrameCount++;

    // Update Display
    // We are running the the context of the capture session. To update the UI in real time, We have to do this in the context of the main thread.
    NSString * frameCountString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%4.4d", iFrameCount];
    [lFrameCount performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(setText:) withObject:frameCountString waitUntilDone:YES];


    //NSLog(@"frame count %d", iFrameCount);
}

- (IBAction)showLeftSideBar
{
    //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    if ([[SidebarViewController share] respondsToSelector:@selector(showSideBarControllerWithDirection:)]) {
        [[SidebarViewController share] showSideBarControllerWithDirection:SideBarShowDirectionLeft];
    }
}

- (IBAction)showRightSideBar:(id)sender
{



}

- (IBAction)flipCamera:(id)sender

{

    AVCaptureDevicePosition desiredPosition;

    if (isUsingFrontFacingCamera)

        desiredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;

    else

        desiredPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionFront;



    for (AVCaptureDevice *d in [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {

        if ([d position] == desiredPosition) {

            [[self session] beginConfiguration];
            AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:d error:nil];
            for (AVCaptureInput *oldInput in [[self session] inputs]) {
                [[self session] removeInput:oldInput];
            }
            [[self session] addInput:input];
            [[self session] commitConfiguration];

            break;

        }

    }

    isUsingFrontFacingCamera = !isUsingFrontFacingCamera;

}

BOOL isUsingFrontFacingCamera;



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark - Guts
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark - View lifecycle
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];


    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}


- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

        flashIsOn=YES;
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Create a preview layer that has a capture session attached to it.
    // Stick this preview layer into our UIView.
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480;

    CALayer *viewLayer = self.vImagePreview.layer;
    NSLog(@"viewLayer = %@", viewLayer);
//    viewLayer.frame =  CGRectMake(-70, 150, 480, 336);


//    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(400, 400), NO, 1);

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

    CGRect bounds=vImagePreview.layer.bounds;
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.bounds=bounds;
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.position=CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds));

    captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.vImagePreview.bounds;
    [self.vImagePreview.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];
    //[self addVideoInputFrontCamera:YES]; // set to YES for Front Camera, No for Back camera

    device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        // Handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
    }
    [session addInput:input];

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // OUTPUT #1: Still Image
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Add an output object to our session so we can get a still image
    // We retain a handle to the still image output and use this when we capture an image.
    stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
    [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];
    [session addOutput:stillImageOutput];


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // OUTPUT #2: Video Frames
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Create Video Frame Outlet that will send each frame to our delegate
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *captureOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    captureOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES; 
    //captureOutput.minFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 3); // deprecated in IOS5

    // We need to create a queue to funnel the frames to our delegate
    dispatch_queue_t queue;
    queue = dispatch_queue_create("cameraQueue", NULL);
    [captureOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
    dispatch_release(queue);

    // Set the video output to store frame in BGRA (It is supposed to be faster)
    NSString* key = (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey; 
    // let's try some different keys, 
    NSNumber* value = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]; 

    NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value forKey:key]; 
    [captureOutput setVideoSettings:videoSettings];    

    [session addOutput:captureOutput]; 
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    // start the capture session
    [session startRunning];

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // initialize frame counter
    iFrameCount = 0;

}



- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
           [session stopRunning];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (IBAction)cancelButton:(id)sender{

}

- (IBAction)flashOn:(id)sender{

    Class captureDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice");
    if (captureDeviceClass != nil) {
        if ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash]){

            [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
            if (flashIsOn) {
                [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
                [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
                oneOff.text=@"On";
                [_flashButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flash-on-button"]];
                _flashButton.accessibilityLabel = @"Disable Camera Flash";
                flashIsOn = NO; //define as a variable/property if you need to know status
            } else {
                [_flashButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flash-off-button"]];
                _flashButton.accessibilityLabel = @"Enable Camera Flash";
                oneOff.text=@"Off";
                [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
                [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
                flashIsOn = YES;
            }
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[self session] stopRunning];
    [super dealloc];
}


- (void)storeFlashSettingWithBool:(BOOL)flashSetting
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:flashSetting forKey:kCameraFlashDefaultsKey];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 13):

Please check your device settings.
Goto privacy ---> Camera ---> check setting for your app-----> turn it on

Run the app. It works.
Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Change your **dealloc Method**

```
[self.captureSession removeInput:self.videoInput];
[self.captureSession removeOutput:self.videoOutput];

 self.captureSession = nil;
 self.videoOutput = nil;
 self.videoInput = nil;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply I will update then let you know

Comment: Still getting crash please check below code                            - (void)dealloc {
    [self.session removeInput:input];
    [self.session removeOutput:captureOutput];
    self.session = nil;
    input = nil;
    captureOutput = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

Comment: call [super dealloc ] as first line

Comment: after call [super dealloc ] as first line  im getting Error Printing description of error:
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11852 "Cannot use Back Camera" UserInfo=0x17c60f20 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot use Back Camera, AVErrorDeviceKey=<AVCaptureFigVideoDevice: 0x17902350 [Back Camera][com.apple.avfoundation.avcapturedevice.built-in_video:0]>, NSLocalizedFailureReason=This app is not authorized to use Back Camera.}[com.apple.avfoundation.avcapturedevice.built-in_video:0]>, NSLocalizedFailureReason=This app is not authorized to use Back Camera.}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63221/discussion-between-2vision2-and-danial-hussain).

Comment: is that complete log.

Answer (score 1):

We had a problem with this today, essentially from iOS 8.0.2 and above access to the camera requires privacy settings to the camera and not the camera roll, once this was enabled the code then worked.

Answer (score 1):

Saw the same error in my app today, I am handling it with an alert that contains a Settings button shortcut to the app's privacy settings.

```
do {
    let captureInput:AVCaptureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: self.device)
    ...
} catch let error as NSError {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title:error.localizedDescription, message:error.localizedFailureReason, preferredStyle:.Alert)
    let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .Default) { (action) in
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
    }
    alert.addAction(settingsAction)
    self.presentViewController(alert,animated:true,completion:nil)
}
```