# Why does switching cameras stop my AVCaptureSession to MovieFileOutput?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturemoviefileoutput

The [iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#Switching_between_devices) says you can add and remove inputs while a session is running, for example to switch between front and back cameras.

However when I try this, my session stops. I'm locking the session with `beginConfiguration` and `commitConfiguration` calls as follows:

```
- (void)switchCamera:(UIButton *)sender {

    dispatch_async([self sessionQueue], ^{

        AVCaptureSession *session = self.captureSession;
        [session beginConfiguration];

        AVCaptureInput *currentInput = self.currentCameraIsBack ? self.videoDeviceInputBack : self.videoDeviceInputFront;
        AVCaptureInput *newInput = self.currentCameraIsBack ? self.videoDeviceInputFront : self.videoDeviceInputBack;

        [session removeInput:currentInput];
        [session addInput:newInput];
        self.currentCameraIsBack = !self.currentCameraIsBack;

        [session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];
        [self setCameraOutputProperties];

        [session commitConfiguration];
    });
}
```

I am outputting to an `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`. Is there anything I need to do to configure this session so it is switchable?

(Note that the OP in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864372/switch-cameras-with-avcapturesession?rq=1) is trying to add a new input without removing the old one, which isn't the problem here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that to do this you need to use an AVAssetWriter and call `appendSampleBuffer:` yourself with the resulting `CMSampleBuffer` like so:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {

    if (self.recording && self.videoWriterInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData) {

        [self.videoWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
    }
}
```