# Swift AVFoundation function to flip camera doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have a function below to toggle between the front and back camera. This function below works, but I have to click a button twice that calls this function for the camera to actually flip. I tried debugging the problem, but can't figure out why the flip only works on the second try. I am not quite sure why the session is behaving like this.

```
    func flipCamera() {
        guard let currentVideoInput = session.inputs.first as? AVCaptureDeviceInput else {
            return
        }

        session.beginConfiguration()
        session.removeInput(currentVideoInput)

        let newCameraPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position = (currentCameraPosition == .back) ? .front : .back
        guard let newCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: newCameraPosition) else {
            session.commitConfiguration()
            return
        }

        do {
            let newVideoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: newCamera)

            if session.canAddInput(newVideoInput) {
                session.addInput(newVideoInput)
                currentCameraPosition = newCameraPosition
            } else {
                session.addInput(currentVideoInput) // Re-add the old input if new input fails
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error creating new camera input: \(error)")
            session.addInput(currentVideoInput) // Re-add the old input in case of error
        }

        session.commitConfiguration()
    }
```

UPDATE code. Instead of removing just the first input, remove all that arnt audio:

```
session.inputs.forEach { input in
    if let deviceInput = input as? AVCaptureDeviceInput {
        let device = deviceInput.device
        
        if !device.hasMediaType(.audio) {
            session.removeInput(input)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [OP ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18070009/ahmed) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77630330/swift-avfoundation-function-to-flip-camera-doesnt-work#comment136896964_77632925):

> It's because my session also had an audio input and during set up it was located at index 1 of the session `inputs` array while the camera was the first index.
> So on the first try removing the camera input works, but then the audio is at the first index and the new camera is at the second index

```swift
session.inputs.forEach { input in
    if let deviceInput = input as? AVCaptureDeviceInput {
        let device = deviceInput.device
        
        if !device.hasMediaType(.audio) {
            session.removeInput(input)
        }
    }
}
```

---

Original answer:

You might need to update the `currentCameraPosition` *before* attempting to switch the camera, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54757886/6309)

```swift
func flipCamera() {
    guard let currentVideoInput = session.inputs.first as? AVCaptureDeviceInput else {
        print("Error: Could not find current video input.")
        return
    }

    currentCameraPosition = (currentCameraPosition == .back) ? .front : .back

    session.beginConfiguration()
    session.removeInput(currentVideoInput)

    guard let newCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: currentCameraPosition) else {
        print("Error: Could not find a camera for the requested position: \(currentCameraPosition).")
        session.commitConfiguration()
        return
    }

    do {
        let newVideoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: newCamera)

        if session.canAddInput(newVideoInput) {
            session.addInput(newVideoInput)
        } else {
            print("Error: Cannot add new video input to the session.")
            currentCameraPosition = (currentCameraPosition == .back) ? .front : .back
            session.addInput(currentVideoInput) // Re-add the old input
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error creating new camera input: \(error)")
        currentCameraPosition = (currentCameraPosition == .back) ? .front : .back
        session.addInput(currentVideoInput) // Re-add the old input
    }

    session.commitConfiguration()
}
```

I have added some logging/error handling to better pinpoint when the feature fails.
The `currentCameraPosition` is updated at the beginning of the method. If adding a new input fails or an error occurs, `currentCameraPosition` is reverted to its previous state.

---

> `session.canAddInput(newVideoInput)` fails, and the old input is added back. I tried wrapping the `canAddInput` function in a dispatch queue that runs with a couple of seconds delay since the process is asynchronous, but this didn't resolve the issue.
> Also, the camera always succeeds on the very first try when flipping. But it fails after that and only the second attempt of every camera flip works.

The behavior where `session.canAddInput(newVideoInput)` is failing on the first attempt but succeeding on the second could be due to the session still being in the process of updating its configuration when `canAddInput` is called.
Since these operations are asynchronous, the session might not be ready to accept a new input immediately after removing the old one.

Given that adding a delay did not resolve the issue, and considering the behavior where [`session.canAddInput(newVideoInput)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/1387180-canaddinput) fails on the first attempt but succeeds on the second, the problem might not be entirely related to timing or the asynchronous nature of the session configuration.

One potential issue could be related to the session still holding onto some aspect of the previous input, preventing the addition of the new input on the first try. To mitigate this, you can attempt a more thorough reset of the session before adding the new input. That might include steps like temporarily stopping the session or explicitly clearing inputs and outputs.

```swift
func flipCamera() {
    guard let currentVideoInput = session.inputs.first as? AVCaptureDeviceInput else {
        print("Error: Could not find current video input.")
        return
    }

    // Update camera position
    currentCameraPosition = (currentCameraPosition == .back) ? .front : .back

    // Attempt to reset the session more thoroughly
    session.beginConfiguration()
    session.removeInput(currentVideoInput)

    // Optionally, stop the session temporarily
    session.stopRunning()

    guard let newCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: currentCameraPosition) else {
        print("Error: Could not find a camera for the requested position: \(currentCameraPosition).")
        session.commitConfiguration()
        return
    }

    do {
        let newVideoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: newCamera)

        // Start the session again before adding new input
        session.startRunning()

        if session.canAddInput(newVideoInput) {
            session.addInput(newVideoInput)
        } else {
            print("Error: Cannot add new video input to the session.")
            // Revert to previous state
            currentCameraPosition = (currentCameraPosition == .back) ? .front : .back
            session.addInput(currentVideoInput)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error creating new camera input: \(error)")
        // Revert to previous state
        currentCameraPosition = (currentCameraPosition == .back) ? .front : .back
        session.addInput(currentVideoInput)
    }

    session.commitConfiguration()
}
```

Temporarily stopping the session with [`session.stopRunning()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/1385661-stoprunning) before removing the input and starting it again with [`session.startRunning()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/1388185-startrunning) before adding the new input. That can help clear any lingering state related to the previous camera input.
[Committing the session configuration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/1388173-commitconfiguration) is done after attempting to add the new input.

Comment: @ahmed I have added some debug printf, to understand where that fails.

Comment: @ahmed OK, I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Hello, as I mentioned previously adding the delay doesn't help. I tried adding a delay of 10 seconds and it still did not do anything.

Comment: @ahmed OK, I have rewritten that last approach.

Comment: I figured it out and added some code in my question. Maybe add the updated code to your solution so I can mark it as correct. But it's because my session also had an audio input and during set up it was located at index 1 of the session inputs array while the camera was the first index. So on the first try removing the camera input works, but then the audio is at the first index and the new camera is at the second index. Thanks for your help a lot, the debugs helped.

Comment: Von a little off topic but I want to create a retail shopping bot (school grad project) such as the 'Valor' bot. I already know how to use selenium to pop up chrome tabs and navigate website. But this is quite slow, I think I have to make a request based bot, I don't have much knowledge on this and thought you might know a little about it. Id appreciate some pointers.

Comment: @ahmed Thank you for the feedback. I have edited the answer to reflect your conclusion.

Comment: @ahmed To create a retail shopping bot similar to the 'Valor' bot, you will need to transition from a Selenium-based approach to one that utilizes HTTP requests. This would significantly speed up your bot, as it bypasses the overhead of a web browser.

Comment: Do you know of any examples/tutorials of how to get started on such a thing. And how to construct such http requests?

Comment: @ahmed A possible framework can be Python + request + beautiful Soup: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-web-data-using-requests-and-beautiful-soup-with-python-3, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ng2o98k983k, https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=zLlHs0jyddQ

Comment: Thanks. Would you be able to help with any of the three below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77670810/swift-add-custom-geometry-view-to-scnnode-in-scenekit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77670678/avfoundation-camera-launches-zoomed-in-swift https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77670659/swift-navigating-away-from-video-causes-crash

Comment: Thanks a lot would you be able to look at this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77698270/swift-ui-custom-video-player-controls-not-working