# Error when adding GeoFire library to Xcode, conflicting dependencies

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geofire

I am trying to add the GeoFire library to my Xcode project so I can use the geo hash query with firebase. When I copy the GitHub url of the GeoFire library and add it to the Xcode package manager to add I get the error below. I already have Firebase added to my project and it is version 10.16. Do I have to remove firebase and add a previous version such as 8.0 since that's what GeoFire depends on. I simply need to create geo hashes and use them as a query for document search. What's the best way I can achieve this?

[image: photo]

"Failed to resolve dependencies Dependencies could not be resolved because 'geofire-objc' depends on 'firebase-ios-sdk' 7.0.0..<9.0.0 and root depends on 'firebase-ios-sdk' 10.16.0..<11.0.0.
"

Comment: Because geofire is dependent on a lower version of firebase, you must either downgrade firebase or update geofire to match.

Comment: @son I don't want to downgrade firebase. How do I update geofire to match? I copied the link of the GeoFire repo of the master branch that's fully up to date. When I try adding it to Xcode I tried "branch", "up to next major version", and "up to next minor version" all did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have:

```bash
┌───────────────┐        ┌────────────────┐
│   Xcode       │        │  GeoFire       │
│  Project      │        │  Library       │
│               │        │                │
│  ┌─────────┐  │        │  Depends on    │
│  │ Firebase│  │        │  Firebase      │
│  │ 10.16   │  │        │  7.0.0.<9.0.0  │
│  └─────────┘  │        └────────────────┘
└───────────────┘
```

And... you cannot downgrade Firebase.

[`firebase/geofire-objc/Package.swift`](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/blob/3724b210a3b3b29e6d7474ea17774d3d4285633d/Package.swift) is clear:

```swift
    dependencies: [
        .package(name: "Firebase",
                 url: "https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git",
                 "7.0.0"..<"9.0.0"),
    ],
```

And the issue [`firebase/geofire-objc` issue 161](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/issues/161) request for Firebase (at least 9.x) for more than a year now.

That issue includes potential workaround:

> Ended up using: https://github.com/emilioschepis/swift-geohash.git

Or:

> At your Podfile use this and everything will work fine
>
> ```
> pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/abdoelmorap/geofire-objc', :tag => '5.4.0'
> ```

Comment: Thanks, although I am not using CocoaPods. Is there anyway I can achieve the same result of this "pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/abdoelmorap/geofire-objc', :tag => '5.4.0'". I tried going to the releases section of the GitHub and I found only up to version 5.0.0 not 5.4.0. https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc/releases

Comment: @ahmed True. I was reporting what I found in that issue, but have not found any additional option for now.

Comment: Ok how do I downgrade Firebase to a version that supports it. Im using firebase for authentication and database storage and queries, would downgrading it to the newest version that supports Geofire cause any problems?

Comment: @ahmed Not sure, as I do not have direct experience with it.