# Using the currently selected camera on iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently implementing a camera view with a toggle to switch between the front and back camera. I use a custom class to define a AVCaptureSession which captures the device input from either the front or the back camera, so I have the following instance vars:

```
private var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
private var backCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
private var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
private var currentCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
```

When the view controller is presented I'd like to set the currentCamera to the one the user has selected in the camera app. Does anyone know if this is possible and if so, how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think unfortunately you can not get these settings.

Comment: This may help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864372/switch-cameras-with-avcapturesession?rq=1

Comment: This question explains how to implement this correctly. For me this already works. I just want to know the users current selected camera (front/back) from the default camera app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately you can not get these settings, which are already saved by user for his/her Camera app.

Comment: Thanks, this would be my guess as well. I'll leave the question a little while longer open just to be sure, but indeed probably not possible.